# How to save file with long path?

Tags: path

I need to save a ".blend" file under the long path, but when i save, i got this message
[image]

I also tried to first create a ".blend" file and overwrite it, but Blender don't overwite, he created a new file with suffix ".blend@".
[image]

Comment: On which OS are you? Very long paths can create problems, for Windows see for example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry

Comment: This does seem to be an OS limitation, (nothing to do with Blender itself.) Can we ask why, for example, these files can't be named/renamed with another representation of those numbers.. e.g.  with those numbers in another base?

Comment: I work on Windows and I have enabled support long path. Paths cannot be changed, they are generated automatically

Comment: When running from the terminal, I get the following message: "'Error: Cannot change old file (file saved with @)', 'Exception: Error: Cannot change old file (file saved with @)'"

Comment: try to change the file name, same problem i got that

Comment: yes, this may be help, but in my situation it is impossible to shorten the path or change file name :(